# doctrine many to many, fetch eager not work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem. I set fetch=eager and dump my entity.
field products = init =false; fetch eager not working? Why?

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Deface\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity \Product", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_basket",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="basket_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_code", referencedColumnName="code")}
 * )
 */
private $products;
```

Comment: What SQL queries were generated?

Comment: `Deface\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity \Product` --- is that whitespace a typo?

Comment: What exactly is "not workin"?